# How to use python's logging to log to the screen and to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I want to log using python's logging to both the screen and a file

this is how I log to the screen:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)    
logging.debug('hello')
```

and this is how I log to a file:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,filename='a.log')   
logging.debug('hello2')
```

Is there a way to log to both the file and the screen?
preferably using logging.basicConfig

I am using python 2.7.14

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321741/printing-to-screen-and-writing-to-a-file-at-the-same-time?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Its not a basic config but there are easy ways to configure in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing to screen and writing to a file at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321741/printing-to-screen-and-writing-to-a-file-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want one logger for the screen and one for the log file, try this:

```
import logging


log = logging.getLogger('logger')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')

fh = logging.FileHandler('test.log', mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(fh)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(ch)
```

This creates two log handlers. When you call `log.debug`/`info`/`warning` etc, it will log to each of your handlers. If the level they are set at is the same or higher, it will log the message, otherwise it won't.

In this example calling `log.debug("test message")` will save the `str` "test message to `test.log`, but you will not see the output on the screen because the `StreamHandler()`'s level is above the `debug` debug.

When you call `log.info("test message")`, it will save the `str` "test message to `test.log` **and** output it to the console because `StreamHandler()`'s level is `info`

`log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` ensures that everything will be logged. If you exclude this line, the default of `WARNING` will be enforced, and **even if you set the level lower in a separate handler**, you won't be able to log anything >= that level

The levels for logging are as follows:

```
DEBUG
INFO
WARNING
ERROR
CRITICAL
```

Comment: I copied your code, added at the end this line: log.info('test') and nothing happend

Comment: it printed this: test3 and in the next line: DEBUG:logger:test3

Comment: @Goolmoos this question is turning out to be harder than I thought. The last edit I made should do it.

Comment: FYI: just tested with python 3.7.2 and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Tried on Python 3.8 and it works nice.
However, I see that the output file becomes readable only after the script has finished, I would need to access it also while the execution is ongoing (i.e. with Tail command).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

I succeeded. here is my code:

```
import logging
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
logging.getLogger('').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh = logging.FileHandler('a.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(fh)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)  
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(ch)
logging.debug('debug message')
```