# How to print to screen and save to file in one-line?

Tags: python, printing

Is it possible to print to screen and save to file in one-line?

The following saves to file:

```
with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
   print('hello world', file=f)
```

And currently to print to screen and save to file would have to do the following:

```
print['hello world')
print('hello world', file=f)
```

I can't find any answers out there for one-line.

I guess a function can be defined to avoid lines in code, but still wondering if it is possible to do all in one line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing to screen and writing to a file at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321741/printing-to-screen-and-writing-to-a-file-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Write a method that do both, then use this method in one-line, `printBoth("This is content")`

Comment: Logging is not quite what I was looking for @azro, but I will revisit it in case I cannot find a solution.

But yes, a method to do both sounds doable

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a **tee** fitting for Python. Such a package - [tee - exists in PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tee/).

You can also build one yourself with a few lines of code - the original author of a big package I maintain did just that, and my code uses it to this day. Of source, there is not need for that, since the package is available.

Comment: Thanks @Amitai Irron! This seems doable, even though I was trying to avoid unnecessary code lines to make it cleaner, but it seems there no way to avoid that.

Answer (score -2):

Try the snipette below, I had success with it in Jupyter Notebook

```
f=open('file.txt','a');print('hello world');f.write('hello world');f.close()
```

Comment: I do not think that is really what he meant.

Comment: This doesn't even save the message to the file.

Comment: Is this even one line?

Comment: This option did not write the message to the file using Python3.7

Comment: The file writes to the directory where you ran the script and I forgot the f.write("Hello World")