# How to redirect another library's console logging messages to a file, in Python

Tags: python, logging

The [fastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) library that I import for an API I have written, writes many logging.INFO level messages to the console, which I would like either to redirect to a file-based log, or ideally, to both console and file. Here is an example of fastAPI module logging events in my console:

[image]

So I've tried to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321741/printing-to-screen-and-writing-to-a-file-at-the-same-time) Stack Overflow answer ("Easy-peasy with Python 3.3 and above"), but the log file it creates ("api_screen.log") is always empty....

```
# -------------------------- logging ----------------------------
logging_file = "api_screen.log"

logging_level = logging.INFO
logging_format = '  %(message)s'
logging_handlers = [logging.FileHandler(logging_file), logging.StreamHandler()]

logging.basicConfig(level = logging_level, format = logging_format, handlers = logging_handlers)
logging.info("------logging test------")
```

Even though my own "------logging test------" message does appear on console within the other fastAPI logs:

[image]

As you can see here it's created the file, but it has size zero.

[image]

So what do I need to do also to get the file logging working?

Comment: Hello Thomas, does this link helps you ? https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues here. First and most importantly: `basicConfig` does nothing if a logger is already configured, which fastAPI does. So the handlers you are creating are never used. When you call `logging.info()` you are sending a log to the root logger which is printed because the fastAPI has added a handler to it. You are also not setting the level on your handlers. Try this code instead of what you currently have:

```
logging_file = "api_screen.log"
logging_level = logging.INFO

logging_fh = logging.FileHandler(logging_file)
logging_sh = logging.StreamHandler()
logging_fh.setLevel(logging_level)
logging_sh.setLevel(logging_level)

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.addHandler(logging_fh)
root_logger.addHandler(logging_sh)

logging.info('--test--')
```

Comment: Works great, and actually because console logging is already set by fastapi, I don't need the streamhandlers, only the filehandler. Now another question, how do I set the message format for logging_fh? Right now it's only printing out the log message but i want to add a timestamp.

Comment: figured it out. Use formatter = logging.Formatter("message format goes here") then logging_fh.setFormatter(formatter).