# Why doesn't the python logging module show my logging to screen if I am in pdb?

Tags: python, logging, pdb

I want to have my `logging.info` show in the terminal/screen in the [Python debugger (pdb)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) and on file. However, it does not appear on the screen. It works in a seperate python console just fine. Why does it not work in pdb? See:

```
bot@18f71e53b3f5:~/pycoq/tutorial$ python brandos_pycoq_tutorial.py
> /home/bot/pycoq/tutorial/brandos_pycoq_tutorial.py(142)<module>()
-> main()
(Pdb) import logging
(Pdb)
(Pdb) level    = logging.INFO
(Pdb) format   = '  %(message)s'
(Pdb) handlers = [logging.FileHandler('./filename.log'), logging.StreamHandler()]
(Pdb)
(Pdb) logging.basicConfig(level = level, format = format, handlers = handlers)
(Pdb) logging.info('Hey, this is working!')
(Pdb) --KeyboardInterrupt--
(Pdb)
```

works in console:

```
bot@18f71e53b3f5:~/pycoq/tutorial$ python
Python 3.9.12 (main, Jun  1 2022, 11:38:51)
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>>
>>> level    = logging.INFO
>>> format   = '  %(message)s'
>>> handlers = [logging.FileHandler('./filename.log'), logging.StreamHandler()]
>>>
>>> logging.basicConfig(level = level, format = format, handlers = handlers)
>>> logging.info('Hey, this is working!')
  Hey, this is working!
>>>
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

the level is set right as refered here: [Printing to screen and writing to a file at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321741/printing-to-screen-and-writing-to-a-file-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 1):

It might be because your `brandos_pycoq_tutorial.py` script does something to `sys.stderr`. It works fine if in `pdb` if you try this:

```
C:\Users\Vinay>python -c "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()"
--Return--
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) import logging
(Pdb) level = logging.INFO
(Pdb) format   = '  %(message)s'
(Pdb) handlers = [logging.FileHandler('./filename.log'), logging.StreamHandler()]
(Pdb) logging.basicConfig(level = level, format = format, handlers = handlers)
(Pdb) logging.info('Hey, this is working!')
  Hey, this is working!
(Pdb)
```

I did this in Windows, but I expect it will work the same way on other platforms.