# How do you run OpenERP yaml unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, odoo, yaml, openerp-8

I'm trying to run unit tests on my openERP module, but no matter what I write it doesnt show if the test passes or fails! Anyone know how to output the results of a test? (Using Windows OpenERP version 6.1)

My YAML test is:

```
- 
  I test the tests
-
  !python {model: mymodelname}: |
    assert False, "Testing False!"
    assert True, "Testing True!"
```

The output when I reload the module with 
openerp-server.exe --update mymodule --log-level=test -dtestdb 
shows that the test ran but has no errors?!

```
... TEST testdb openerp.tools.yaml_import: I test the tests
```

What am I doing wrong?

*Edit: ---------------------------------------------------------------------*

Ok so after much fiddling with the !python, I tried out another test:

```
- 
    I test that the state
-
!assert {model: mymodel, id: mymodel_id}:
    - state == 'badstate'
```

Which gave the expected failure:

```
WARNING demo_61 openerp.tools.yaml_import: Assertion "NONAME" FAILED
test: state == 'badstate'
values: ! active == badstate
```

So I'm guessing it is something wrong with my syntax which may work as expected in version 7.

Thanks for everyone's answers and help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I've tried. It seems to work for me:

```
!python {model: sale.order}: |
    assert True, "Testing True!"
    assert False, "Testing False!"
```

(Maybe you forgot the "|" character)

And then :

```
bin/start_openerp --init=your_module_to_test -d your_testing_database --test-file=/absolute/path/to/your/testing_file.yml
```

You might want to create your testing database before :

createdb mytestdb --encoding=unicode

Hope it helps you

UPDATE: Here are my logs ( I called my test file sale_order_line_test.yml)

```
ERROR mytestdb openerp.tools.yaml_import: AssertionError in Python code : Testing False!
mytestdb openerp.modules.loading: At least one test failed when loading the modules.
loading test file /path/to/module/test/sale_order_line_test.yml
AssertionError in Python code : Testing False!
```

Comment: still no joy :( I used the --test-file param, and it is clear from the log that it ran the test twice (once for the init and once for the test-file) but no failed test and nothing in the test-report-directory.. must be something wrong with my tests or maybe I should upgrade openerp coz this should be working.

Comment: I've awarded the bounty to this answer, because although still cant get it to work, it is the most complete. Thanks for your help

Comment: when you say "seems to work for me" - where did you see the failed message? in the server logs?

Comment: Which version of OpenERP are you using? For me too it tests 2 times. I updated my answer so that you can see the logs I get

Comment: Im using v 6.1, I see yours works correctly.. I must have missed something, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I'm using v 7.0. Try to upgrade and let me know how it works for you

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the docs (e.g. [here](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/contribute/15_guidelines/coding_guidelines_testing.html) and [here](http://v6.openerp.com/node/969)), I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code.

However, I'm not familiar with `--log-level=test`. Maybe try running it with the `-v`, `--debug` or `--log-level=debug` flags instead of `--log-level=test`? You may also need to try the uppercase variants for the `--log-level` argument, i.e. `--log-level=DEBUG`.

`test` certainly isn't one of the standard Python [logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)'s [logging levels](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial), and while I can't exclude the possibility of them [adding a custom log level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183233/how-to-add-a-custom-loglevel-to-pythons-logging-facility), I don't think that's the case.

It might also be worthwhile trying to remove the line `obj = self.browse(cr, uid, ref("HP001"))`, just in case..

Comment: according to the docs:   --log-level=LOG_LEVEL
specify the level of the logging. Accepted values:
['info', 'debug_rpc', 'warn', 'test', 'critical',
'debug_sql', 'error', 'debug', 'debug_rpc_answer',                  'notset']

and:

--test-report-directory=TEST_REPORT_DIRECTORY
If set, will save sample of all reports in this                     directory.

tried both and no luck

Answer (score 3):

Try to type following path on your terminal when you start your server.

> `./openerp-server --addons-path=<..Path>...`--test-enable

:Enable YAML and unit tests.

> `./openerp-server --addons-path=<..Path>...`--test-commit

:Commit database changes performed by YAML or XML tests.

Comment: error: no such option: --test-enable

the --test-commit has no effect, from the docs I imagine that is used to commit the db changes made by the test otherwise they are rolled back

Comment: if you work on V7 then follow above option which i posted yesterday. But if you are working on 6.1 then...... used this command   ./openerp-server.py --addons-path=../../addons -u <module name> -d <db name> -- test-commit

Comment: @Timothy : when you start your server or update the module then does your .yml file load with other files? please look at once.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. the yml file does load - it shows the "TEST testdb openerp.tools.yaml_import: I test the tests" but doesnt show any failed (or passed) test

Comment: @Timothy if your test case run without any error then check in your system. demo data would be there for respective model which you write for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your terminal it will work.

```
./openerp-server --addons-path=<..Path> --log-level=test --test-enable
```

Hope This will help you.

Comment: which version are you using? I get a "error: no such option: --test-enable".. I'm using v6.1