# Python3 add logging level

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I have this code which works just fine for me.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

logger = None


def create_logger():
    global logger
    logger = logging.getLogger('Logger')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler("C:/Users/user/Desktop/info.log", maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=20)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)


create_logger()
logger.info("Text info")
logger.debug("Text debug")
logger.warning("Text warning")
logger.error("Text error")
logger.critical("Text critical")
```

And the output looks great:

> 2017-12-19 15:06:43,021 - Logger - INFO - Text info
> 2017-12-19 15:06:43,021 - Logger - DEBUG - Text debug
> 2017-12-19 15:06:43,022 - Logger - WARNING - Text warning
> 2017-12-19 15:06:43,022 - Logger - ERROR - Text error
> 2017-12-19 15:06:43,022 - Logger - CRITICAL - Text critical

Well, I want to add a new logging level like this:

```
logger.message("Text message")
```

And the output should be like this

> 2017-12-19 15:06:43,022 - Logger - MESSAGE - Text message

Comment: How is "message" different than "info" or any of the other levels?

Comment: see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183233/how-to-add-a-custom-loglevel-to-pythons-logging-facility/ for a detailed discussion how to add new logging levels.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [Logging documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging.html#custom-levels) (emphasis added):

> Defining your own levels **is possible, but should not be necessary**, as
>   the existing levels have been chosen on the basis of practical
>   experience. However, if you are convinced that you need custom levels,
>   great care should be exercised when doing this, and **it is possibly a
>   very bad idea to define custom levels if you are developing a library**.
>   That’s because if multiple library authors all define their own custom
>   levels, there is a chance that the logging output from such multiple
>   libraries used together will be difficult for the using developer to
>   control and/or interpret, because a given numeric value might mean
>   different things for different libraries.

An overview of default [logging levels](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging.html#logging-levels):

[image]

**But if you still want to, you can make your own log level:**

In the `logging`-module, `_levelToName` and `_nameToLevel` are mappings between logging names and levels. Instead of manually adding to them, the `addLevelName()` function does this for you.

Here, a new logging level called *MESSAGE* is added with log level *25*:

```
import logging

# Define MESSAGE log level
MESSAGE = 25

# "Register" new loggin level
logging.addLevelName(MESSAGE, 'MESSAGE')  # addLevelName(25, 'MESSAGE')

# Verify
assert logging.getLevelName(MESSAGE) == 'MESSAGE'
```

If you don't want to make your own logger class but still wants to log other log levels, then you can use the `Logger.log(level, msg)`-method on the traditional loggers:

```
logging.log(MESSAGE, 'This is a message')
```

#### EDIT: Add message directly

```
 def message(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.isEnabledFor(MESSAGE):
        self._log(MESSAGE, msg, args, **kwargs)
```

Make the `message()`-function available in `logging`:

```
 logging.message = message
 # or setattr(logging, 'message', message)
```

Make the `message()`-function available in the logger:

```
 logging.Logger.message = message
 # or setattr(logging.Logger, 'message', message)
```

#### Make custom Logger class

You could make your own logger class to make a `message(msg)`-method, to be used similarily as the others (e.g. `info(msg)`, `warning(msg)`, etc.)

In the following example, a new logger is made with a `message(msg)`-method to log *MESSAGE*:

```
class MyLogger(logging.Logger):
    def message(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.isEnabledFor(MESSAGE):
            self._log(MESSAGE, msg, args, **kwargs)
```

#### Get logger

I'm not sure of what's the best way to make it work with `logging.getLogger(name)`, but below are two approaches. 
Ref. comments, I believe the first approach is better:

**Either** make the new logger the default logging class, which means new logger instances will be of the `MyLogger` class instead of the default `logging.Logger` class:

```
logging.setLoggerClass(MyLogger)
logger = logging.getLogger('A new logger name')
logger.message('This seems to work')
assert isInstance(logger, MyLogger)
```

**Or** just make an instance of the logger and add it to the `loggerDict` in the active `logging.Manager` instance (**EDIT**: not recommended, see comments):

```
my_logger = MyLogger('Foo')
logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict['Foo'] = my_logger
logger = logging.getLogger('Foo')
logger.message('This is the same instance as my_logger')
assert logger is my_logger
```

#### Use the new log level

```
# Use the new logger class
logger.warning('Custom log levels might be a bad idea')
logger.message('Here is a message')
# Log with custom log level:
logger.log(MESSAGE, 'This is a message')
```

This assumes that `MESSAGE` is predefined as an integer numerical value representing the log level. (E.g. *25* as previously mentioned)

Comment: Generally your answer is good, but some of the things you suggest involve use of logging internals, which might not be a good idea. For example, instantiating a logger instance (`MyLogger`) directly, or manually updating the manager's `loggerDict`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated my answer with the intentions of addressing your comment, but I'd love any additional feedback,.

Comment: Great explanation! Covers everything I was looking for. Plus one for that.