# Adding log level with Python 3.7

Tags: logging, python-3.7

I've been trying to add a custom log level by following these two excellent posts:

[How to add a custom loglevel to Python's logging facility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183233/how-to-add-a-custom-loglevel-to-pythons-logging-facility/16955098)

[Python3 add logging level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888855/python3-add-logging-level)

In my top level __init__.py I've put:

```
    import logging

    logging.VERBOSE = 15 
    logging.addLevelName(logging.VERBOSE, "VERBOSE")

    def verbose(self, message, *args, **kws):
        if self.isEnabledFor(logging.VERBOSE):
            # Yes, logger takes its '*args' as 'args'.
            self._log(logging.VERBOSE, message, args, **kws) 

    setattr(logging, 'verbose', verbose)
    setattr(logging.Logger, 'verbose',verbose)
#also tried
# logging.Logger.verbose=verbose
# logging.verbose=verbose

logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

In the various other class and sub-modules, I'm expecting that I can then:

```
import logging
.
.
.
logging.verbose("Someone sent us up the bomb")
```

But, all that gets me is:

```
TypeError: verbose() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

If I switch to:

```
logging.log(logging.VERBOSE, "Intent Returned: " + intent_name)
```

I don't get an exception thrown, but I don't get any message printed either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The self is what is stopping this from working since it seems you are not operating from within a class.

If you are using [Basic Config](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) you can add a custom level this way in your `__init__.py` or `__main__.py`:

```
import logging
log_level = 15  

logging.basicConfig(
    level=int(log_level),
    format="%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-7.7s]  %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler('put your log path here'),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ]
)

def verbose(msg, *args, **kwargs):
    if logging.getLogger().isEnabledFor(15):
        logging.log(15, msg)

logging.addLevelName(15, "VERBOSE")
logging.verbose = verbose
logging.Logger.verbose = verbose

# now try the new level
logging.verbose("This is verbose logging")
```

This also works in other files if you are using the standard logger across them all.

Comment: The critical part was to leave off the args and **kwargs in the public call to log().  The absolute minimum code that can be put into the base init file and have it work anywhere in the project is: `import logging
logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(logging.NullHandler())

logging.VERBOSE = 15 
logging.addLevelName(logging.VERBOSE, "VERBOSE")

def verbose(message, *args, **kws):
    if logging.getLogger().isEnabledFor(logging.VERBOSE):
        # Yes, logger takes its '*args' as 'args'.
        logging.log(logging.VERBOSE, message) 

logging.verbose=verbose`