# Python logging setLevel what does integer input mean?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

Take a look at this link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#levels

They talk about logging levels where `DEBUG` has a numeric value of `10`, `INFO` has a numeric value of `20`.

I am looking at a program where `handler.setLevel(level=15)` was used.  Obviously, this is a custom logging level.  How to add one is discussed in this answer: [Python3 add logging level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888855/python3-add-logging-level)

I found the `logging` documentation to be inadequate in answering these questions:

- What does `15` mean in context of logging?
- Does it mean it's almost `DEBUG`?  Why not just use `INFO` level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python3 add logging level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888855/python3-add-logging-level)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does 15 mean in context of logging? Does it mean it's almost DEBUG?

It means something higher than DEBUG (10) yet lower than INFO (20).

> Why not just use INFO level?

In stdlib logging it's possible to [add your own custom levels](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#custom-levels).  See [`logging.addLevelName`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.addLevelName) for example. In practice, it's not uncommon for third party code to use a TRACE level (5) for sub-DEBUG logging.

It's likely that something in the program you're looking at has added a level between DEBUG and INFO when configuring logging.

Comment: Can you make up an example when you would want to use something between `DEBUG` and `INFO`?  Why wouldn't you just use `DEBUG`?

Comment: For when DEBUG is too verbose and INFO is not verbose enough? Actually happens to me a lot, to be honest..