# python after logging.debug() how to view its logrecord

Tags: python, python-logging

Recently I came across logging in python.

I have the following code in test.py file

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logger.debug("test Message")
```

Now, is there any way I can print the resulting `Logrecord` object generated by `logger.debug("test Message")` because it's stated in the documentation that

> LogRecord instances are created automatically by the Logger every time something is logged

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects

I checked saving `debug` into a variable and print it

```
test = logger.debug("test Message")
print(test)
```

the output is `NONE`

My goal is to check/view the final Logrecord object generated by `logging.debug(test.py)` in the same test.py by using `print()` This is for my own understanding.

```
print(LogrecordObject.__dict__)
```

So how to get hold of the `Logrecord` object generated by `logger.debug("test Message")`

Comment: debug() doesn't return anything. The logging record it generates is sent down to the logging module and processed through whatever handlers you have configured. If you really want to examine the record that gets passed through, you might want to implement your own handler and add it to the logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way if you just wish to view the LogRecord attributes, you can specify a subset of them as string replacements in a giant string like below.

```
import logging

view_all_logrecord_attributes = """
asctime - %(asctime)s
created - %(created)f

filename - %(filename)s
funcName - %(funcName)s
levelname - %(levelname)s
levelno - %(levelno)s
lineno - %(lineno)d
message - %(message)s
module - %(module)s
msecs - %(msecs)d

name - %(name)s
pathname - %(pathname)s
process - %(process)d
processName - %(processName)s
relativeCreated - %(relativeCreated)d

thread - %(thread)d
threadName - %(threadName)s
"""

logging.basicConfig(format= view_all_logrecord_attributes, level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('Message text here')
```

The list is from the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

And an example output would be:

```
asctime - 2024-02-21 08:42:10,428
created - 1708465330.428894

filename - <stdin>
funcName - <module>
levelname - DEBUG
levelno - 10
lineno - 1
message - Message text here
module - <stdin>
msecs - 428

name - root
pathname - <stdin>
process - 94365
processName - MainProcess
relativeCreated - 749

thread - 8042958848
threadName - MainThread
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no return in `debug()`

```
# Here is the snippet for the source code
    def debug(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.isEnabledFor(DEBUG):
            self._log(DEBUG, msg, args, **kwargs)
```

If you wanna get LogRecord return, you need to redefine a `debug()`, you can overwrite like this:

```
import logging

DEBUG_LEVELV_NUM = 9 
logging.addLevelName(DEBUG_LEVELV_NUM, "MY_DEBUG")

def _log(self, level, msg, args, exc_info=None, extra=None, stack_info=False):
    sinfo = None
    fn, lno, func = "(unknown file)", 0, "(unknown function)"
    if exc_info:
        if isinstance(exc_info, BaseException):
            exc_info = (type(exc_info), exc_info, exc_info.__traceback__)
        elif not isinstance(exc_info, tuple):
            exc_info = sys.exc_info()
    record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args,
                             exc_info, func, extra, sinfo)
    self.handle(record)
    return record


def my_debug(self, message, *args, **kws):
    if self.isEnabledFor(DEBUG_LEVELV_NUM):
        # Yes, logger takes its '*args' as 'args'.
        record = self._log(DEBUG_LEVELV_NUM, message, args, **kws)
        return record

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.Logger.my_debug = my_debug
logging.Logger._log = _log
logger.setLevel(DEBUG_LEVELV_NUM)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
test = logger.my_debug('test custom debug')
print(test)
```

Reference:
[How to add a custom loglevel to Python's logging facility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183233/how-to-add-a-custom-loglevel-to-pythons-logging-facility)

Comment: I want to view the Logrecord created. What you show is about returning the message.

Comment: so, you wanna get Logrecord  printed?

Comment: Yes, As you know the Logrecord has lot of attributes like thread, asctime, pathname, processName etc (check https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes). So i wanted to view that.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the custom loglevel thing

Comment: my pleasure. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a handler that instead of formatting the LogRecord instance to a string, just save it in a list to be viewed and inspected later:

```
import logging
import sys


# A new handler to store "raw" LogRecords instances
class RecordsListHandler(logging.Handler):
    """
    A handler class which stores LogRecord entries in a list
    """
    def __init__(self, records_list):
        """
        Initiate the handler
        :param records_list: a list to store the LogRecords entries
        """
        self.records_list = records_list
        super().__init__()

    def emit(self, record):
        self.records_list.append(record)


# A list to store the "raw" LogRecord instances
logs_list = []

# Your logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Add the regular stream handler to print logs to the console, if you like
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))

# Add the RecordsListHandler to store the log records objects
logger.addHandler(RecordsListHandler(logs_list))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    logger.debug("test Message")
    print(logs_list)
```

Output:

```
test Message
[<LogRecord: __main__, 10, C:/Automation/Exercises/222.py, 36, "test Message">]
```