# Ignore specific logging line temporarily

Tags: python, logging

I have a method called `import_customers()` which loads csv-like data.

This methods logs to log-level INFO.

In one case I want to avoid this logging.

I see several ways:

Variant 1: a new kwarg like `do_logging=True` which I can switch to false.

Variant 2: Use some magic context which ignores this line.

```
with IgnoreLoggingContext() as context:
    import_customers()
```

How could I implement `IgnoreLoggingContext()`?

If you think V1 is better, then please leave a comment.

Comment: Don't understand what are you still looking for...? There are at least two valid answers. Or if you have more requirements you should specify them in your question.

Comment: @Sraw I am curious. Yes, there are two valid answers. Maybe someone knows a third solution.

Comment: Immediate thought is you can set a custom logging level for this, see or similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183233/how-to-add-a-custom-loglevel-to-pythons-logging-facility

Comment: @stacksonstacks I don't understand why a custom logging level does help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on your need. If you want to disable the whole logging, it would be the simplest:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import logging


@contextmanager
def IgnoreLoggingContext():
    root = logging.getLogger()
    origin_level = root.getEffectiveLevel()
    root.setLevel(logging.WARNING) # Or whatever you want
    yield
    root.setLevel(origin_level)

with IgnoreLoggingContext():
    do_something()
```

Or you can pass a variable to the manager to specify which logger to disable:

```
@contextmanager
def IgnoreLoggingContext(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    origin_level = logger.getEffectiveLevel()
    logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING) # Or whatever you want
    yield
    logger.setLevel(origin_level)
```

Answer (score 3):

Loggers can be completely disabled via the `disabled` attribute. Another thing is that loggers do not necessarily propagate to the root logger and can define own record handling, so the complete disabling could look like this:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def off():
    loggers = [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
    # turn loggers off
    for logger in loggers:
        logger.disabled = True
    logging.root.disabled = True
    yield
    # turn loggers back on
    for logger in loggers:
        logger.disabled = False
    logging.root.disabled = False
```

Usage example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.info('foo')
    with off():
        logging.info('bar')
```

will print

```
INFO:root:foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the logging level from INFO to ERROR and when you're done change it back.

```
# Beginning of file
rootLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Change logging level to only log to error, just prior to calling your method
rootLogger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

# Change it back when you're done
rootLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: This overwrites the log level if it was DEBUG at the beginning. And it does not set the old level again if an exception was raised. But basically I think you are right: first read the current log level. Then try-except-finally and set the old level again in the finally block.