# python custom log level naming convention

Tags: python, logging

We are planning to have a custom log level in our python application

```
VERBOSE_LEVEL = 5 #VERBOSE log level.(VERBOSE < DEBUG)
logging.addLevelName(VERBOSE_LEVEL, "VERBOSE")
```

We thought of going with either VERBOSE or TRACE for the custom log.
I though VERBOSE will be more precise but libraries like LOG4J in java has TRACE as lower log level than DEBUG.
Any suggestion on which one to select?

Comment: In your case you want debug level as trace in python, so you can add override the debugv to go to a lower level than `debug`. This discussion will solve your query
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183233/how-to-add-a-custom-loglevel-to-pythons-logging-facility

Comment: In my case custom log level is working fine(VERBOSE or TRACE). Even i added a method for verbose by extending the logging adapter in python. Just curious on which name I have pick. I think verbose will be fine in my case. @blhsing thanks for your valuable time