# How to make a good custom logging level in python?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I use the **logging** just plasing `logging.mylog('message')` in my different files.
And I have this format:

```
logging.basicConfig(format = u'[%(asctime)s] # %(levelname)-4s\t%(filename)s[LINE:%(lineno)d]\t%(message)s', level = logging.MYLOG)
```

I took the function **addLoggingLevel** from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35804945/4647888

and found that **filename** always printed as **main.py** because I declare **addLoggingLevel** function in this file. Never mind in which file "logging.mylog('message')" placed.

So my question is: how to add a custom logging level with full support of standard levels behavior and with no surprises?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What’s missing from the current logging implementation? You may want to take a closer look at the [`LogRecord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord)… ?

Comment: You should get the logger per module: `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` and use that instead of `logging`.

Comment: I trying to achieve different filenames of mylog() call not main.py every time. Why cant I use ```logging``` like with standard loglevel methods?