# What is pythonic way to return customized object

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a question specifically about what is the proper way to achieve what I am doing. The code below works perfectly, it does exactly what I want. When I call `CustomLogger()` it returns a logger with the desired formatting, however, I am looking to add some arguments to it to expand its functionality which is easy, but it got me thinking of what is the right python way to actually make this class look like. Returning a customized object via `__new__` is NOT the right way, and I understand this, but I can't just customize the property via `__init__` because I am returning a non-class object, I am returning a property on the object instead. I am not necessarily looking for someone to rewrite the class to do what I want, I am looking to gain an understanding of how it should be written and why.

tldr: How do I write this class the proper way, instead of hijacking the `__new__`.

```
import logging, logging.handlers
from datetime import datetime

class CustomLogger():
    nlog = logging.getLogger()

    def __new__(self) -> logging.Logger:
        self.addLoggingLevel(levelName='VERBOSE',levelNumber=15)
        self.addLoggingLevel(levelName='FATAL',levelNumber=15,exitAfter=True,force=True)
        self.addLoggingLevel(levelName='TRACE',levelNumber=9)

        self.nlog.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

        # create console handler with a higher log level
        consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
        consoleHandler.setFormatter(self.CustomFormatter())
        self.nlog.addHandler(consoleHandler)

        #If we should enable tracing funtions.
        self.nlogTrace = logging.TRACE >= self.nlog.getEffectiveLevel()
        return self.nlog

    def addLoggingLevel(levelName:str, levelNumber:int, methodName:str=None, exitAfter:bool=False,force:bool=False):
        """
        Comprehensively adds a new logging level to the `logging` module and the currently configured logging class.
        `levelName` becomes an attribute of the `logging` module with the value
        `levelNum`. `methodName` becomes a convenience method for both `logging`
        itself and the class returned by `logging.getLoggerClass()` (usually just
        `logging.Logger`). If `methodName` is not specified, `levelName.lower()` is
        used.
        To avoid accidental clobberings of existing attributes, this method will
        raise an `AttributeError` if the level name is already an attribute of the
        `logging` module or if the method name is already present
        Example
        -------
        >>> addLoggingLevel('TRACE', logging.DEBUG - 5)
        >>> logging.getLogger(__name__).setLevel("TRACE")
        >>> logging.getLogger(__name__).trace('that worked')
        >>> logging.trace('so did this')
        >>> logging.TRACE
        5
        """
        if not methodName:
            methodName = levelName.lower()

        levelName = levelName.upper()

        if force != True:
            if hasattr(logging, levelName):
                print('\x1b[33;21m' + f"Warning: '{levelName}'' already defined in logging module" + '\033[0m')
                return
            if hasattr(logging, methodName):
                print('\x1b[33;21m' + f"Warning: '{methodName}'' already defined in logging module" + '\033[0m')
                return
            if hasattr(logging.getLoggerClass(), methodName):
                print('\x1b[33;21m' + f"Warning: {methodName} already defined in logger class" + '\033[0m')
                return

        # This method was inspired by the answers on Stack Overflow post
        # http://stackoverflow.com/q/2183233/2988730, especially
        # http://stackoverflow.com/a/13638084/2988730
        if exitAfter == True:
            def logForLevel(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
                if self.isEnabledFor(levelNumber):
                    self._log(levelNumber, msg, args, **kwargs)
                exit()
        else:
            def logForLevel(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
                if self.isEnabledFor(levelNumber):
                    self._log(levelNumber, msg, args, **kwargs)

        def logToRoot(msg, *args, **kwargs):
            logging.log(levelNumber, msg, args, **kwargs)

        logging.addLevelName(levelNumber, levelName)
        setattr(logging, levelName, levelNumber)
        setattr(logging.getLoggerClass(), methodName, logForLevel)
        setattr(logging, methodName, logToRoot)

    class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
        """
        Logging Formatter to add colors and count warning / errors
        'Grey' = "\x1b[38;21m"; 'Yellow' = "\x1b[33;21m"; 'Red' = "\x1b[31;21m"; 'boldRed' = "\x1b[31;1m"; 'Reset' = "\x1b[0m"
        """

        def format(self, record):
            FORMATS = {
                logging.TRACE:    "\x1b[38;21m" + '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d ' + '%(lineno)04d:%(module)-10.10s ' + '%(threadName)-10.10s ' + '[%(levelname)-8s] ' + '%(message)s' + "\x1b[0m",
                logging.VERBOSE:  "\x1b[38;21m" + '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d ' + '%(lineno)04d:%(module)-10.10s ' + '%(threadName)-10.10s ' + '[%(levelname)-8s] ' + '%(message)s' + "\x1b[0m",
                logging.DEBUG:    "\x1b[38;21m" + '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d ' + '%(lineno)04d:%(module)-10.10s ' + '%(threadName)-10.10s ' + '[%(levelname)-8s] ' + '%(message)s' + "\x1b[0m",
                logging.INFO:     "\x1b[38;21m" + '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d ' + '%(lineno)04d:%(module)-10.10s ' + '%(threadName)-10.10s ' + '[%(levelname)-8s] ' + '%(message)s' + "\x1b[0m",
                logging.WARNING:  "\x1b[33;21m" + '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d ' + '%(lineno)04d:%(module)-10.10s ' + '%(threadName)-10.10s ' + '[%(levelname)-8s] ' + '%(message)s' + "\x1b[0m",
                logging.ERROR:    "\x1b[31;21m" + '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d ' + '%(lineno)04d:%(module)-10.10s ' + '%(threadName)-10.10s ' + '[%(levelname)-8s] ' + '%(message)s' + "\x1b[0m",
                logging.CRITICAL: "\x1b[31;1m"  + '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d ' + '%(lineno)04d:%(module)-10.10s ' + '%(threadName)-10.10s ' + '[%(levelname)-8s] ' + '%(message)s' + "\x1b[0m",
                logging.FATAL:    "\x1b[31;1m"  + '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d ' + '%(lineno)04d:%(module)-10.10s ' + '%(threadName)-10.10s ' + '[%(levelname)-8s] ' + '%(message)s' + "\x1b[0m"
            }
            #Establish new time format.
            convertedTimeStamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created)
            logDateFmt = convertedTimeStamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

            #Determine correct string format based on level.
            logFormat = FORMATS.get(record.levelno)

            #Set new format.
            formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt=logFormat,datefmt=logDateFmt)
            return formatter.format(record)
```

I simply call the following to extend the functionality to any class.

```
class Example():

    def __init__(self):
        #Setup logging.
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            nlog = CustomLogger()
        else:
            nlog = getLogger(__name__)

        #Set per-module logging level.
        nlog.setLevel(20)
```

Comment: If you want a call to your class's constructor to not return an instance of the class, then what makes you think overriding `__new__` is the wrong solution? It is the *only* solution, if you want `CustomLogger` to actually be a class rather than a function that makes use of a class.

Comment: @kaya3 of course I can't find it now, but I read that the only time your supposed to overwrite __new__ is if you're changing an immutable object? like str, int, etc or something. I can't find the exact article and posts on stack overflow, but probably because I am sleep-deprived atm.

Comment: Well, that sounds wrong, or at the very least it sounds like you can't think of a specific problem with your code as it is now. Lots of people have lots of opinions about how you're "supposed to" write code; I would worry less about what rules they tell you to follow, and more about what their reasons are for inventing those rules.

Comment: If you want to call a class to create some other class, why don't you use a method instead? This avoids doing "unexpected returns".

Comment: @Tzane, honestly, I think you're right.  I am pretty sure  I am overthinking this...