# Add custom log level for pytest tests to python the logging module

Tags: python, logging, pytest

I am using `pytest` and I wish to log some log output that will be captured and displayed should a test fail.

To do this, I wish to add a new log level to the default `pytest` logger. My rationale for this is that my application outputs to the `INFO` level anyway, so I wish to avoid capturing those logs during the test. For that reason, I cannot simply change the log level to `INFO`.

Using the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183233/how-to-add-a-custom-loglevel-to-pythons-logging-facility) I have derived the following solution, but it is not working. The error I see appears to be noted in a comment on accepted answer to the question, but there is no response.

> AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'test_info'

How can I correctly add a custom logging level?

#### Using `pytest` fixture and tests

```py
import logging
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def logging_format(level_name: str='TEST_INFO', level_number: int=31):

    def log_test_info(self, message, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.isEnabledFor(level_number):
            self._log(level_number, message, args, **kwargs)

    logging.addLevelName(level_number, level_name)
    setattr(logging, level_name, level_number)
    setattr(logging.getLoggerClass(), level_name.lower(), log_test_info)


def test():
    logging.test_info('Some log data.')
    assert True
```

#### Not using `pytest` fixture and tests

To be sure this is not a `pytest` issue, I it's also possible to replicate the issue without using it.

```py
import logging

level_name = 'TEST_INFO'
level_number = 31

def log_test_info(self, message, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.isEnabledFor(level_number):
        self._log(level_number, message, args, **kwargs)

logging.addLevelName(level_number, level_name)
setattr(logging, level_name, level_number)
setattr(logging.getLoggerClass(), level_name.lower(), log_test_info)

logging.test_info('Some log data.')
assert True
```

Comment: In your example, you are adding the constant TEST_INFO to the logging module but adding the log_test_info function to the logger class.
You need to use `logging.getLogger()` to get an instance of the root logger that you can call use to call `test_info`, alternatively, use `logging.log(level_number, "Some log data.")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code there is a misunderstanding between a logger *instance* and the logger *module*.

To be able to call the `test_log` method in the original code you need to obtain a logger instance eg:

```py
# After the existing code

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.test_info("Some log data.")
```

As you have added the `test_info` method to the `loggerClass` it will be available to the logger *instance*.

To have the method available on the logging *module* the function needs to be created for that purpose and added to the module:

```py
# After the existing code

def module_test_info(message, *args, **kwargs):
    logging.log(level_number, message, *args, **kwargs)

setattr(logging, level_name.lower(), module_test_info)
```

This will add the `module_test_info` function to the `logging` module with the name `test_info` you will be able to call it as such `logging.test_level("Some log data.")`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation here and your comment on my question. You are correct, I was misunderstanding the intricacies of the module vs the instance. I have added the new level as in my question and then implemented `logging.log(LEVEL, 'msg')` as that is more than sufficient for my use case.